# How to call a PostgreSQL stored procedure with a custom type parameter form java

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE seg_type AS
(
    _timestamp bigint,
    segment_type bigint,
    area_type bigint,
);
```

And I have a java class:

```
public class Segment
{
    private Long ts;
    private Long seg_type;
    private Long area_type;
}
```

In addition I have a stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SomeFunc(seg_type[])
```

I'm using **postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar** to connect to my DB. And I want to be able to call my stored procedure from the java code with Segment[] like this:

```
String query = new String("{call SomeFunc(?)}");
CallableStatement stmt = dbConn.prepareCall(query);
stmt.setObject(1, Segment[], Type);
```

If this is the correct implementation so what should I put in the Type?
or maybe the implementation is incorrect?

Comment: I had a quick look in the PgJDBC test suite and didn't find a test case for arrays of composite types. You might be able to use the standard Java array features (`createArray` and so on), but you'll probably have to `implements PGobject` for your type and handle the composite field packing/unpacking yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution could be the following:

Create a function in the `java` Segment class that creates a string in the format of a postgreSQL type.

```
public class Segment
{
   private Long ts;
   private Long seg_type;
   private Long area_type;

   public pgType(){
      return String.format("\"(%d,%d,%d)\"",
         this.ts, this.seg_type, this.area_type)
   }
}
```

Note: for different data types you might need to format the string differently.

This will return a the following string `"(ts, seg_type, area_type)"` that represents the `seg_type` type in postgres.

now, you'll need to itirate through the `Segment[]` array to form a `postgres array`.

```
StringBuilder segTypeArray = new StringBuilder("{");
segTypeArray.append(segments.[0].getDBValue());  
for(int i = 1; i < segments.length; i++){
   segTypeArray.append("," + list.get(i).getDBValue());
}
segTypeArray.append("}");
```

This will create a `postgres array` of `seg_type` type
`{"(ts, seg_type, area_type)","(ts, seg_type, area_type)",.....}`

When you create the query string, make sure to cast to seg_type[]

```
String query = new String("{call SomeFunc(?::seg_type[])}");
CallableStatement stmt = dbConn.prepareCall(query);
stmt.setObject(1, segTypeArray.toString());
```